# Substitute 2 Non-default lines regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, syntax, substitution

I'd like to replace the reg expression of "hh:mm:ss" of 2 strings in Perl with "xx:xx:xx" How can I accomplish this?

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $l="12:48:25 - Properties - submitMode : 2";
my $r="54:01:00 - Properties - submitMode : 2";
#my $newLn;
#Find "hh:mm:ss" in $_ :P
if ($l =~ /\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/ || $r=~ /\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/) {
#print "Time found";
s/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/xx:xx:xx/g; #looking for default $_ , but have $l and $r
s/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/xx:xx:xx/g;    
     #substitute with xx: p
print $l,"\n";
print $r,"\n";
} else {
print "No time found found";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$l =~ s/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/xx:xx:xx/g;
$r =~ s/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/xx:xx:xx/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

*toolic's* solution works, but if you want to use the substitution command with the default variable `$_`, use a `foreach` loop, like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $l="12:04:25 - Properties - submitMode : 2";
my $r="54:01:00 - Properties - submitMode : 2";
#my $newLn;
#Find "hh:mm:ss" in $_ :P
#if ($l =~ /\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/ || $r=~ /\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/) {

for ( $l, $r ) { 
    s/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/xx:xx:xx/g || 
        do { 
            print "Not time found in $_\n"; 
            next 
        };
    print $_,"\n";
}
```